# Nginx: Why is $host variable not available in stream directive in nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

in my nginx.conf I would like to pass the request depending on the requested url to a specific server infrastructure.

Everything works great apart from the $host variable.
I get error "nginx: [emerg] unknown "host" variable"

From my understanding is $host a regular variable and I dont have to declare it first.. in fact its used in the http directive above without problems:

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    ...
}
```

But in stream it is a problem...

```
stream {
        map $ssl_server_name $targetBackendSSL {
            test1.example.com  192.168.1.1:22553;
            test2.example.com  192.168.1.2:22553;
        }
        
        map $host $targetBackendNonSSL {
            test1.example.com  192.168.1.9:22553;
            test2.example.com  192.168.1.10:22553;
        }
        
        # ssl
        server {
                listen 8000 ssl;
                listen [::]:8000 ssl;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
                proxy_pass $targetBackendSSL;
        }
        
        # non-ssl
        server {
                listen 8001;
                listen [::]:8001;  
                proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
                proxy_pass $targetBackendNonSSL;
        }
}
```

Any help appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `stream{}` block handles [TCP and UDP Load Balancing](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/).
2. The [`$host` variable](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) comes from a HTTP request.

   > `$host`
   >  in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or
   > host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name
   > matching a request

Such information is not commonly available in TCP or UDP streams, as it is a [concept of the HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-host-and-authority). Therefore, it is impossible to have such a variable.

The [`$ssl_server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_server_name), on the other hand, comes from the Server Name Indication (SNI), which is a TLS extension ([RFC 6066, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3)). It is available on protocols that provides this information in the *extended client hello*. Not all TLS wrapped TCP protocols support SNI; your detection is not reliable.

Comment: Thank you! Makes total sense now.